# Inheritance with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, inheritance, inotifypropertychanged

I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve the following problem... I have a base class that needs to update it's `modifiedDateTime` property when a derived class property is changed.

#### BaseObject.cs

```
public class BaseObject
{
    private DateTime? _modifiedDateTime;

    public DateTime? modifiedDateTime 
    {
        get { return _modifiedDateTime ; }
        set { _modifiedDateTime  = value; }
    }

    public BaseObject
    {
        _modifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    public void Update(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _modifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    }
}
```

#### ExampleClass1.cs

```
public class ExampleClass1: BaseObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _data;

    public int data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set 
        {
            _data = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("data"));               
        }
    }

    public ExampleClass1()
    {
        PropertyChanged += base.Update;
    }
}
```

The previous example is working as expected.

However if the derived class contains an object of another class. For example:

#### ExampleClass2.cs

```
public class ExampleClass2: BaseObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _data;

    private ExampleClass1 _objClass1;

    public int data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set 
        {
            _data = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("data"));               
        }
    }

    public ExampleClass1 objClass1
    {
        get { return _objClass1; }
        set 
        {
            _objClass1 = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("objClass1"));               
        }
    }

    public ExampleClass2()
    {
        PropertyChanged += base.Update;
    }
}
```

When I change the `data` property of the `objClass1`, the `modifiedDateTime` property of the `ExampleClass2` inherited by the base class `BaseObject` is not updated.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: when you set the value of `objClass1` subscribe to its property changed event as well

Comment: is there any way that this could be done automatically ... in a more generic way..

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: If you find yourself using the PropertyChanged event alot you should really consider a base class with something like `RaisePropertyChanged` from MVVM light (https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)/ObservableObject.cs) to make the event raising cleaner as you will be able to simply write `RaisePropertyChanged(() => data)`, which on the plus side also makes refactoring easier. Also in c# properties are usually PascalCase and not camelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the value of `objClass1` subscribe to its property changed event as well

```
public ExampleClass1 objClass1 {
    get { return _objClass1; }
    set {
        //in case one already existed. unsubscribe from event
        if(_objClass1 != null) _objClass1.PropertyChanged -= base.Update
        _objClass1 = value;
        //subscribe to event
        if(_objClass1 != null) _objClass1.PropertyChanged += base.Update
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("objClass1"));               
    }
}
```